# select option value is not setting using jquery in any browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on cakephp search filter. I have select boxes such as country , company , employee etc. based on selection it populates data in to the next select box and give result after click on submit button. This is all i have done with the help of ajax. I got result but after search result i want to show my selection criteria in my select box it self.

```
//search form
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array('class'=>'filter-form', 'novalidate' => true, 'action'=>'', 'type' => 'get', 'error'=>true, 'inputDefaults'=>array('div'=>false, 'label'=>false), 'errorMessage' => false)); 
         if ($user['role_id'] == ADMIN ){
                echo $this->Form->input(null, array('name'=>'con', 'options'=>$countries,'id'=>'country12', 'value' =>isset($datasearch['con'])?$datasearch['con']:'','empty'=>__('Select Country'), 'class'=>'field-inline keyword' ));
                echo $this->Form->input(null, array('name'=>'com', 'options'=>$company,'id'=>'company12', 'value' =>isset($datasearch['com'])?$datasearch['com']:'', 'empty'=>__('Select Company'), 'class'=>'field-inline keyword' ));

        }
        echo $this->Form->input(null, array('name'=>'q', 'options'=>$empdata, 'value' =>isset($datasearch['q'])?$datasearch['q']:'', 'id'=>'employee', 'empty'=>__('Select Employee'), 'class'=>'field-inline keyword' ));
        echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search'), array('class'=>'field-inline'));
        echo $this->Form->end(); 
        ?> 

// js code
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( window ).load(function() {
        <?php if(!empty($this->params->query)){ ?>
            $("#country12").trigger("change");
            var com = "<?php echo isset($this->params->query['com']) ?   $this->params->query['com'] : '' ?>";
            alert("Searching progress completed");
            $("#company12 option[value=" + com +"]").prop('selected', true);
    <?php } ?>

   });
</script>
```

I have added alert in JS code above then it selects the value from select box after trigger but it works only in mozila. I dont want to use alert and need to display value in select box in any browser.

I have tried val() as well but won't work. Looking for help.

Comment: if i remove  $("#country12").trigger("change"); then it works but i want selection based on country and company list box should show companies which comes under selected country. can any one help me on this ?

Comment: Why on earth did you tag this with "cakephp" but not "jquery"? I've updated the tags. Please take a moment in the future and think about which tags you're going to use.

Comment: @burzum - Can you please help me with query i posted . Thanks for correction in tags